# changing value in in-AppPurchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

i have a valu in in-AppPuchase inr Rs:55 that is $0.99 and now my question is how to change the value of Rs:55 to $9.99
i dint find solution for this any where please help

[image: in app purchase alert view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change it in [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/)

Got to "Manage Yours Apps" -> select your application -> "Manage in app purchases" (in the right column) -> select in-app purchase -> "Edit" -> Under "Price Schedule" you'll see drop down list named "Price tier" - as you select some tier you'll see it's details and price.

Comment: do u have procedure how to change canu pls tell me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change it, the price is displayed according to the region settings of your device. People in the US will see $9.99